# Convergence region for improper integral

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

What is the convergence region for the improper integral: $\displaystyle\int_1^\infty \dfrac{x^\alpha}{1+x^\alpha} \, dx$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\alpha\geq 0$ then
$$\dfrac{x^\alpha}{1+x^{\alpha}}\sim_\infty 1\quad (\text{or}\ \frac{1}{2}\ \text{if}\ \alpha=0)$$
and hence the integral is divergent,

and if $\alpha<0$ then
$$\dfrac{x^\alpha}{1+x^{\alpha}}\sim_\infty \frac{1}{x^{-\alpha}}$$
so the integral is convergent iff $-\alpha>1\iff\alpha<-1$.